# Creating multiple columns from one function (and then averaging over them) in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Starting from:

```
dates <- yday(ceiling_date(dmy(sapply(1:11, function(x) paste0("01/", x, "/2009"))), "month") %m-% days(1))

foo <- data.frame(id = 1:1000000) %>%
  mutate(
    datdeb = round(runif(n(), 1, 365)),
    datfin = round(runif(n(), datdeb, 365)),
    etp = runif(n()),
    group = round(runif(n(), 1, 1000))
  )
```

the most basic version of what I want to do is:

```
for(i in 1:11){
  foo <- foo %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(
      test = sum((dates[i] >= datdeb & dates[i] <= datfin))
    ) %>%
    rename(!!paste0("size_date", dates[i]) := "test")
}

res1 <- foo %>%
  mutate(
    m_size = rowMeans(across(starts_with("size_date")))
  ) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    m_size = mean(m_size)
  )
```

Now I want to do this in the fastest way possible given that my ultimate dataset I'm applying this on is huge.

For the first bit the alternative I have come up with is:

```
foo <- bind_cols(foo, map_dfc(1:11, ~ foo %>%
                          group_by(group) %>%
                          transmute(!!paste0("size_date", dates[.x]) := sum((dates[.x] >= datdeb & dates[.x] <= datfin)))
                          ) %>% select(starts_with("size_date")))
```

But somewhat surpringly to me, this ended up being slower when benchmarked with tictoc.

For the second part I came up with two other options:

```
res2 <- foo %>%
  mutate(
    m_size = rowMeans(across(starts_with("size_date")))
  ) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    m_size = m_size[1]
  )

res3 <- foo %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  mutate(
    m_size = rowMeans(across(starts_with("size_date")))
  )
```

Unsurprisingly the last option is quite a bit faster.

I was wondering whether there are even faster (and more elegant?) ways of getting this done? In particular, potentially combine the two steps in an intelligent way with a incremental cumulative mean?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to keep it in the `tidyverse`? Because going faster may very well mean leaving it behind.

Comment: Are you thinking data.table? I guess that would be good to, though I admit often settle for the tidyverse because I love readable it is ...

Comment: For something straight forward like this, you might have some luck with `dtplyr`. Best of both worlds... the `dplyr` API with `data.table` speed.

Comment: Yes! It's been on my radar, haven't gotten around to it yet! Does it lose a lot of speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a more elegant way, but I doubt that it is really performant. One way to do it would be to use `purrr::map_dfc` and loop over the `dates` vector.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dates <- yday(ceiling_date(dmy(sapply(1:11, function(x) paste0("01/", x, "/2009"))), "month") %m-% days(1))

foo <- data.frame(id = 1:1000000) %>%
  mutate(
    datdeb = round(runif(n(), 1, 365)),
    datfin = round(runif(n(), datdeb, 365)),
    etp = runif(n()),
    group = round(runif(n(), 1, 1000))
  )

foo %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(m_size = rowMeans(
    map_dfc(set_names(dates, dates),
            ~ sum(.x >= datdeb & .x <= datfin))
    )
  ) %>% 
  summarise(m_size = mean(m_size))
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#>    group m_size
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1   141.
#>  2     2   258.
#>  3     3   298.
#>  4     4   283.
#>  5     5   286.
#>  6     6   274.
#>  7     7   263.
#>  8     8   273 
#>  9     9   272.
#> 10    10   261.
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you are interested in the intermediate columns than I have a package on Github called {dplyover} which can loop over vectors to create nicely named columns. It is not very performant, but looking at the benchmarks it seems perform not too bad (see benchmarks below).

```r
library(dplyover) # https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/

 foo %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(over(dates,
                ~ sum(.x >= datdeb & .x <= datfin),
                .names = "size_date{x}"))

#> # A tibble: 1,000,000 x 16
#> # Groups:   group [1,000]
#>       id datdeb datfin    etp group size_date31 size_date59 size_date90
#>    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>
#>  1     1    233    234 0.0322   581          82         154         218
#>  2     2    185    305 0.452    956          97         171         221
#>  3     3    237    281 0.0410   735          90         162         232
#>  4     4    255    290 0.290    646          86         159         222
#>  5     5     57    215 0.762    748          78         156         245
#>  6     6     42    218 0.343    243          80         154         215
#>  7     7     52     66 0.329    238          75         145         215
#>  8     8    138    158 0.724    681          81         150         221
#>  9     9     19    135 0.285    542          87         172         235
#> 10    10    300    330 0.0665    61          79         151         212
#> # … with 999,990 more rows, and 8 more variables: size_date120 <int>,
#> #   size_date151 <int>, size_date181 <int>, size_date212 <int>,
#> #   size_date243 <int>, size_date273 <int>, size_date304 <int>,
#> #   size_date334 <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This would be my `data.table` approach, but I think, there are better ways to do it, and maybe other users chime in here.

```r
foo_dat <- as.data.table(foo)

foo_dt[, paste0("size_date", 1:11) := lapply(dates,
                                             function(x) {
                                               sum(x >= datdeb & x <= datfin)
                                       }),
       by = group
       ][,
         .(m_size = rowMeans(.SD)),
         by = group,
         .SDcols = paste0("size_date", 1:11)
       ][,
         .(m_size = mean(m_size)),
         by = group
       ]
```

**Benchmarks**

Here are some benchmarks for the four approaches mentioned above: the original `loop`, `map`, `over` and `data.table`. I had some trouble with the loop, therefore I included `foo <- foo2` to undo the changes. To be fair, I added a similar line, although not necessary, to the other three approaches. `over` was surprisingly faster than expected, but still far from being really performant. Admittedly, my `data.table` approach is not really efficient. There are definitely better ways to do this in `data.table` which should be much faster.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover
library(data.table)


dates <- yday(ceiling_date(dmy(sapply(1:11, function(x) paste0("01/", x, "/2009"))), "month") %m-% days(1))

foo <- data.frame(id = 1:1000000) %>%
  mutate(
    datdeb = round(runif(n(), 1, 365)),
    datfin = round(runif(n(), datdeb, 365)),
    etp = runif(n()),
    group = round(runif(n(), 1, 1000))
  )

foo_dt <- as.data.table(foo)
foo2 <- foo

test <- bench::mark(iterations = 50L, check = FALSE,
            
            "loop" = {

              for(i in 1:11){
                foo <- foo %>%
                  group_by(group) %>%
                  mutate(
                    "size_date{i}" := sum((.env$dates[i] >= datdeb & .env$dates[i] <= datfin))
                  )
              }

              foo %>%
                mutate(
                  m_size = rowMeans(across(starts_with("size_date")))
                ) %>%
                group_by(group) %>%
                summarise(
                  m_size = mean(m_size)
                )

              foo <- foo2
            },

            "map" = {

              foo2 %>%
                group_by(group) %>%
                mutate(m_size = rowMeans(
                  map_dfc(set_names(dates, dates),
                          ~ sum(.x >= datdeb & .x <= datfin))
                )
                ) %>%
                summarise(m_size = mean(m_size))
              foo <- foo2
            },

            "over" = {

              foo2 %>%
                group_by(group) %>%
                mutate(m_size = rowMeans(
                  over(dates,
                       ~ sum(.x >= datdeb & .x <= datfin),
                       .names = "size_date{x}")
                )
                ) %>%
                summarise(m_size = mean(m_size))
              foo <- foo2
            },
            
            "datatable" = {
              foo_dt[, paste0("size_date", 1:11) := lapply(dates, function(x) sum(x >= datdeb & x <= datfin)),
                         by = group
              ][,
                .(m_size = rowMeans(.SD)),
                by = group,
                .SDcols = paste0("size_date", 1:11)
              ][,
                .(m_size = mean(m_size)),
                by = group
              ]
              
              foo <- foo2
            })

#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
  
test
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 loop          1.45s    1.61s     0.627     727MB     3.95
#> 2 map        916.06ms 998.53ms     0.985     186MB     5.24
#> 3 over       649.82ms 701.65ms     1.37      186MB     4.29
#> 4 datatable  856.88ms 921.75ms     1.06      271MB     1.80
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Awesome! I think I'm also going to check the performance of dtplyr!

Comment: Strangely when I do it, data.table is much much faster (I'm not considering over because it's not on CRAN and hence can't use it sorry!) and dtplyr goes back to the normal tidy version.

Comment: Also while it doesn't seem to make any difference for data.table, it does quite inelegant to collapse using mean even though everything is equal in each group (interestingly doing something like m_size[1] seems to make it slower)

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for the feedback. Are you using my `data.table` code? I thought that the code is inefficient, but if the same code is running much faster on your computer, I should reinstall. Also `dtplyr` will not be faster than `data.table` i(t has a small overhead). But syntax-wise it might be more readable.